# finding a formula in terms of both x and y for y

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> $y$ is directly proportional to the cube of $x$. $y=20h$ when $x=h$ and $h$ is not zero. Find a formula for $y$ in terms of $x$ and $h$.

Here's what I did:

$y=kx^3$ and $k = {x^3\over y} = {x^3\over20h}$

Therefore, ${x^3\over20h} \times x^3 = {x^6\over20h} = y$.

The correct answer is $20x^3\over h^2$.

Comment: $k=\frac y{x^3}$, not $\frac{x^3}y$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $y(x)=kx^3$ and $y(h)=20h,$ thus

$$20h= k h^3,$$

hence

$$k= \frac{20}{h^2},$$

Therefore

$$y(x)= \frac{20x^3}{h^2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

telf24!

Here you have your answer, but let me first tell you a little bit about StackExchange. Here, we should not ask questions about our homework, at least not directly, you should only ask specific doubts and show how you tried to solve them.

Now, you know $y(x) = kx^3$ for a fixed $k$, this is true for any $x$. Also, when $x = h$, you have $y = 20h$.

This means $kh^3 = 20h$, which allows you to solve for $k$ provided you can divide by $h^3$, and you can because $h \neq 0$. Thus,
$$k = \frac{20}{h^2}.$$
Now, just substitute this into $y = kx^3$, the general relation between $x$ and $y$, and you're done:
$$y(x) = \frac{20}{h^2}x^3.$$